# Divergence in GPGPU

Tags: cuda, opencl, gpgpu

I know that in case of divergence both if and else are executed on GPU for each work item and finally with the help of mask we select the one. But I can't understand that we if both are being executed then how it increases the idleness in execution units.

I have gone through few questions on stackoverflow but they don't relate to how it effects idleness of execution units.

Can anyone explain me this concept clearly? How divergence increases stalls or idleness in execution units?

Comment: If both branches has to be executed then why threads don't take the same branch at one time

Comment: OK let me break my question. If there is divergence does both if and else executed for same thread. As per my knowledge both are executed but serially. Please correct me here if you think I am wrong

Comment: Ohk. Your explanation is using warp. Thanks for this. Can I say for the individual thread both if and else are executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mask is not used after both code paths have been executed to select one  result, but different masks are used during the execution to enable only the threads within the current warp that are active in the currently executed code path.

Let us look at a small example with a 8-wide SIMD unit (real GPU SIMD units are 32 (NVidia) or 64-ops (AMD GCN) wide):

```
if ((threadIdx.x % 2) == 0)   
{
   a = b+c;   // Even threads
} else
   a = b*c;   // Odd threads
}
d = a*2
```

This gets executed as:

1. `if ((threadIdx.x % 2) == 0)       // MASK: 11111111 all threads enabled`
2. `a = b+c;    // MASK: 10101010, only even threads enabled, odd threads idle`
3. `a = b*c;    // MASK: 01010101, only odd threads enabled, even threads idle`
4. `d = a*2     // MASK: 11111111, all threads are enabled again`

Line 4 is called the "recovergence point" because the control flows that split at Line 1 merge back here. In Line 2 and Line 3 only half of the execution units are used and other execution units stay idle. So during the execution of these lines the performance of the GPU is halved.

Answer (score 2):

Few points after the discussion with @Mai Longdong:
Idle time of Execution Units: is the time when the execution units are not doing any useful work.

At every cycle, a warp can execute at most one instruction on at most 32 data elements (or whatever the warp width is). If you need to execute two different instructions (as is the case with warp divergent branches), you need to issue those over two cycles.

When we use if and else both branches are executed for the entire warp. But if first thread takes a if then it is disabled while the rest of the warp takes the else. It will not do anything until the rest of the warp finishes the else. Which can be considered a waste of execution units (when compared to branch less code). When first thread will be executing others will be disabled. This leads to decrease in amount of useful work, hence increase in idle time of execution units.

if all 32 items in a warp are executing taking only if condition path or else condition path then there is no increase in the idle time of execution units. You can refer to the discussion at [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87334/discussion-between-mai-longdong-and-manish-kumar)