# Branch divergence in GPGPU

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

```
__golbal__ void function(){

... some codes... 

if(0<A<512){

... a few codes...
}

else if (512<=A){

... a lot of codes...
}

... some codes...
}




int  main(){
some code for GPU...
...
for(int i=0; i<1024 ; i++){
A[i] = i;
}
...
some code for GPU...
}
```

[Divergence in GPGPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32086032/divergence-in-gpgpu)

I'm studying GPGPU, and I became curious about the branch divergence.
I know that when treating branch divergence in GPU, it uses SIMT stack, and selected threads in the same warp will be executed and the others will not. And then, if all threads in the same warp are not selected, the instructions will be executed or not?

for example,
In the above code, half of threads will take **if** and the other **half** will take else if. If all A are less than 512 in threads that are in the same warp, dose the instructions about **else if** will be executed? or just skip them.

Comment: https://www2.eecs.berkeley.edu/Pubs/TechRpts/2016/EECS-2016-143.pdf
P.18 - 19. I found an example about my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> for example, In the above code, half of threads will take if and the other half will take else if. If all A are less than 512 in threads that are in the same warp, dose the instructions about else if will be executed? or just skip them.

Just skip.

If all threads in the same warp have an instruction [predicated](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#instruction-statements) off, the instruction will not be issued, and will not consume execution resources *for that warp*.

That is the reason for the statement/suggestion on slide 53 [here](https://www.nvidia.com/docs/IO/116711/sc11-perf-optimization.pdf):

```
Avoid diverging within a warp
– Example with divergence:
• if (threadIdx.x > 2) {...} else {...}
• Branch granularity < warp size
– Example without divergence:
• if (threadIdx.x / WARP_SIZE > 2) {...} else {...}
• Branch granularity is a whole multiple of warp size
```

Effectively there is "no divergence" if the conditional boundaries align with the warp boundaries. This is considered an "optimization".

To wit, from the same slide as above:

> • Different warps can execute different code with no impact on
> performance